# Does computet convert every single ascii digit (in binary) to its numerical equivalent (in binary)?

Tags: c

Does computet convert every single ascii digit (in binary) to its numerical equivalent (in binary) ?
Let's say if 9 is given as input then its ascii value will be  00111001 and we know that binary of 9 is 1001 then how  computer will convert ascii value of 9 to binary of 9.

Comment: The ASCII table is constructed in such a way that `'9' - '0'` gives the value 9.

Comment: As for “does it convert every single digit”, only when you tell it to. It doesn’t know what the data is you give it unless you tell it what to do with it. It’s just bits and operations for the processor, it doesn’t know anything about ASCII or anything.

Comment: There's no conversion. If you read a character, it will be stored in its encoded form (whatever that encoding might be).

Answer (score 1):

It is only when doing arithmetic that a bit pattern represents a numeric value to a digital computer. (It would be possible to create a digital computer that doesn't even do arithmetic.)

It is a human convenience to describe bit patterns as numbers. Hexadecimal is the most common form because it is compact, represents each bit in an easily discernable way and aligns well with storage widths (such as multiples of 8 bits).

How a bit pattern is interpreted depends on the context. That context is driven by programs following conventions and standards, the vast majority of which are beyond the scope of the computer hardware itself.

Some bit patterns are programs. Certain bits may identify an operation, some a register, some an instruction location, some a data location and only some a numeric value.

If you have a bit pattern that you intend represents the character '9' then it does that as long as it flows through a program where that interpretation is built-in or carried along. For convenience, we call the bit pattern for a character, a "character code".

You could write a program that converts the bit pattern for the character '9' to the bit pattern for a particular representation of the numeric value 9. What follows is one way of doing that.

C requires that certain characters are representable, including digits '0' to '9', and that the character codes for those characters, when interpreted as numbers, are consecutive and increasing.

Subtraction of two numbers on a number line is a measure the distance between them. So, in C, subtracting the character code for '0' from the character for any decimal digit character is the distance between the digit and '0', which is the numeric value of the digit.

```
'9' - '0'
```

equals the 9 because of the requirements in C for the bit patterns for character codes and the bit patterns for integer.

Note: A binary representation is not very human-friendly in general. It is used when hexadecimal would obscure the details of the discussion.

Note: C does not require ASCII. ASCII is simply one character set and character encoding that satisfies C's requirements. There are many character sets that are supersets of and compatible with ASCII. You are probably using one of them.

Answer (score -1):

Try this sample program, it shows how ASCII input is converted to a binary integer and back again.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int myInteger;
    printf("Enter an integer: ");
    scanf("%d",&myInteger);  
    printf("Number = %d",myInteger);
    return 0;
}
```

It's a bit crude and doesn't handle invalid input in any way.

Comment: It doesn't show how ASCII is converted. On a machine using EBCDIC it would dot the same. It only shows there are functions that convert input to internal numeric representation and back.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie it may not do what you'd like but it, most likely, is what the vague OP is looking for.